# JavaScript Prime Number Generator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a JavaScript prime number generator that lists every prime between 1 and 100. I know this is a common programming exercise and there's an abundance of solutions on the web. My question is why does my solution result an empty array? Here's the code:

```
var primeNumbers = [];
for (var x=2; x<101; x++)
    if (x%2 === 0) 
    {
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        for (var y=2; y<101; y++) 
        {
            if (x/y > 1) 
            {
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                primeNumbers.push(x);
            }
        }
    }
};
console.log(primeNumbers);
```

Comment: Please note how to format your code in future. Also, you've missed the opening brace after the `for` statement

Comment: Plz understand the break operation....

Comment: @NoshBrinken - If you go to edit your question you'll see that you use 4 spaces for tabs. The use of ` is for one-off lines of code

Comment: A few good prime generators can be found in [prime-lib](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib) today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You break when `x%2 === 0`, so you exit the loop at once. Reverse the condition and enter the code in the loop directly:

Replace this:

```
if (x%2 === 0) {
  break;
}
else {
```

with:

```
if (x%2 !== 0) {
```

**Problem 2:** You are exiting the inner loop if `x/y > 1`. This is the same as the condition `x > y`, so that will always exit the inner loop immediately. Instead make the inner loop run from two and up to one less than `x`:

```
 for (var y=2; y<x; y++) {
```

**Problem 3:** Instead of dividing `x` by `y` and comparing to one, you should use the modulo operator: `x%y`. If the result is zero, then `x` is not a prime number.

**Problem 4:** You are adding prime numbers inside the inner loop, so you will end up with most numbers multiple times, not just prime numbers once.

You need to add a variable to keep track of what's happening in the inner loop. If *none* of the checks in the inner loop are zero, then you can add `x` to the list of prime numbers.

Comment: the number 2 is missing in the array isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Because the first thing you do is break if `x % 2 === 0`.  Which is true immediately.  `break` will exit the loop.  I think you want `continue`.

Comment: +1 - Might want to explain that break stops the loop too (as opposed to continue).

Comment: Anyways, the code posted by OP is incorrect, since the array length is coming out to be `2450` after the using `continue`. It should something less than 100.

Comment: I was just trying to get him started by pointing out the first thing that occurred to me.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the break operation. I was under the impression that break would stop the loop only for that iteration, not completely end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to test every number before the limit, you just have to test the prime numbers you found before that number.
If you were looking to find all prime numbers between 1 and 10, when you are testing 7 for example you should test

```
7%2 === 0 false
7%3 === 0 false
7%5 === 0 false
```

than 7 is a prime number and your prime number array should be

```
[0,1,2,3,5,7]
```

and as you see I didn't test 4 because 4 isn't a prime number. This are the numbers you will test 8

```
8%2 === 0 true > return false
```

and you don't have to test more because you already know it isn't a prime number. So the final solution should be like

```
function getPrimes(x){
        var ar = [];
        for (var counter = 0; counter <= x; counter++) {
            var notPrime = false;
            for (var i = 2; i <= ar.length && !notPrime; i++) {
                if (counter%ar[i]===0) {
                    notPrime = true;
                }
            }
            if (notPrime === false) ar.push(counter);
        }
        console.log(ar)
    }
    getPrimes(250);
```

Comment: Why should 0 and 1 be part of the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var funPrimeNumber=function(val){

 var iniX=2;
 var iniY=2;
 var flag=1;
 while(iniX<val){
            iniY=2; 
            flag=1;
                 while(iniY<iniX){
                     if(iniX%iniY==0){
                         //NOT PRIME NUMBER 
                         flag=0;
                     } 
                 iniY++;
                }

                 if(flag==1){
                    //PRIME NUMBER 
                    document.write(iniX + ", ");
                 }
        iniX++;          
      }
}
```

funPrimeNumber(100);

Comment: Could you add some text to explain how your solution works?